# Floor braces stix 2 not showing properly

Tags: pdftex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,ragged2e,relsize,graphicx,bbm,mathtools}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix2}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix2}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{xsymbols}{LS1}{stix2scr}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{xlargesymbols}{LS2}{stix2ex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lfloor}{\mathopen}{symbols}{"E2}{xlargesymbols}{"08}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rfloor}{\mathclose}{symbols}{"E3}{xlargesymbols}{"09}

\begin{document}
Why am i not getting $\lfloor x\rfloor$ properly?
\end{document}
```

When I am running pdflatex, I am not getting the output of the floor symbol. I am attaching the output here [image] Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get

```
Missing character: There is no <E2> in font cmsy10!
Missing character: There is no <E3> in font cmsy10!
```

because you have a typo: `symbols` instead of `largesymbols`. That is, assuming you want to use the glyphs from STIX2. Don't forget `\makeatletter` because of `\noaccents@`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,ragged2e,relsize,graphicx,bbm,mathtools}

\makeatletter
%\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
\makeatother
%\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix2}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix2}{m}{n}
%\DeclareSymbolFont{xsymbols}{LS1}{stix2scr}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{xlargesymbols}{LS2}{stix2ex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lfloor}{\mathopen}{xlargesymbols}{"E2}{xlargesymbols}{"08}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rfloor}{\mathclose}{xlargesymbols}{"E3}{xlargesymbols}{"09}

\begin{document}

I am getting $\lfloor x\rfloor$ properly.

\end{document}
```

[image]

With also `\lbrace` and `\rbrace` (but they don't really match with other fonts).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,ragged2e,relsize,graphicx,bbm,mathtools}

\makeatletter
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
\makeatother
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix2}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix2}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixoperators}{LS1}{stix2}{m}{n}
%\DeclareSymbolFont{stixsymbols}{LS1}{stix2scr}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixlargesymbols}{LS2}{stix2ex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lfloor}{\mathopen}{stixlargesymbols}{"E2}{stixlargesymbols}{"08}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rfloor}{\mathclose}{stixlargesymbols}{"E3}{stixlargesymbols}{"09}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrace}{\mathopen} {stixoperators}{"5E}{stixlargesymbols}{"0C}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rbrace}{\mathclose}{stixoperators}{"60}{stixlargesymbols}{"0D}

\begin{document}

I am getting $\lfloor x\rfloor$ properly.

I am getting $\lbrace x\rbrace$ properly.

I am getting $\{x\}$ properly.

\bigskip

$
\biggl\{\biggl\lfloor \Bigl\{\Bigl\lfloor \bigl\{\bigl\lfloor \{\lfloor
%
\biggl\rfloor\biggl\} \Bigl\rfloor\Bigl\} \bigl\rfloor\bigl\} \rfloor\}
$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Yes, there's a big jump from `\Big` to `\bigg`: one has to reduce a bit the factor. Left as exercise.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please add the commands for the \lbrace and \rbrace as well. I still have a problem with that. Thanks a ton for the kind help.

Comment: @crskhr I added the necessary parts. The problem with `\bigg` is for you to solve.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the kind help. Very nice of you to do the needful.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to declare `\lfloor` and `\rfloor` again. They already exists. Pdflatex is not the problem here.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,ragged2e,relsize,graphicx,bbm,mathtools}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix2}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix2}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{xsymbols}{LS1}{stix2scr}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{xlargesymbols}{LS2}{stix2ex}{m}{n}
% \DeclareMathDelimiter{\lfloor}{\mathopen}{symbols}{"E2}{xlargesymbols}{"08} <- Not necessary
% \DeclareMathDelimiter{\rfloor}{\mathclose}{symbols}{"E3}{xlargesymbols}{"09} <- Not necessary

\begin{document}
Why am i not getting $\lfloor x\rfloor$ properly?
\end{document}
```

produces
[image]

By the way you just need:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    You can get $\lfloor x \rfloor$ properly.
\end{document}
```

to obtain

[image]